# How can I create a Python timestamp with millisecond granularity?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I need a single timestamp of milliseconds (ms) since epoch.  This should not be hard, I am sure I am just missing some method of `datetime` or something similar.

Actually microsecond (µs) granularity is fine too. I just need sub 1/10th second timing.

Example.  I have an event that happens every 750 ms, lets say it checks to see if a light is on or off.  I need to record each check and result and review it later so my log needs to look like this:

```
...00250 Light is on
...01000 Light is off
...01750 Light is on
...02500 Light is on
```

If I only have full second granularity my log would look like this:

```
...00 Light is on
...01 Light is off
...01 Light is on
...02 Light is on
```

Not accurate enough.

Comment: Just to clarify - a microsecond is a millionth of a second, a millisecond is a thousandth of a second

Comment: micro or milli is fine.  I just need less than 1/10 of a second (a centisecond)

Comment: 0.1s is a decisecond.  A centisecond is 0.01s.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
import time
time.time() * 1000
```

where 1000 is milliseconds per second. If all you want is hundredths of a second since the epoch, multiply by 100.

Comment: ..or `int((time.time() + 0.5) * 1000)` to get it as the nearest integral number of ms.

Comment: @bgporter: Or `int(round(time.time() * 1000))`.

Comment: ok, so time.time() is giving me decimal seconds with a 1/100 granularity.  That will do.

Comment: Well, except that I need to pull it out of exponential notation

Comment: @Skip: `int(round(time.time() * 1000))` gives me `1300819189007`. Are you doing something weird with it?

Comment: Ah, the round is what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

In Python, `datetime.now()` might produce a value with more precision than `time.time()`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc) # use POSIX epoch
posix_timestamp_millis = (now - epoch) // timedelta(milliseconds=1) # or `/ 1e3` for float
```

In theory, `time.gmtime(0)` (the epoch used by `time.time()`) may be different from `1970`.

Comment: To get your code to work, I add to add datetime.datetime to the calls

Comment: @TomChapin wrong. The code in the answer works as is. Look at the import in the very first line in the code.

Answer (score 4):

Note that although you can multiply `time.time()` with your desired degree of precision, it does not guarantee your device actually has that precision. For example, it has only +-1 ms precision on windows ([source](https://peps.python.org/pep-0564/#annex-clocks-resolution-in-python)). **For improved accuracy, use:**

```py
import time

now_ns = time.time_ns() # Time in nanoseconds
now_ms = int(now_ns / 1000000)
```

Only works from Python 3.7+